# Repaired bug in RoR app stay in Chrome

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome

Example situation:
I had bug in my controller mysite.sk/profil/5. My site show me /error500, it's ok, but... I repaired this bug, but when I open mysite.sk/profil/5 in my Google Chrome,it show me /error500. When I open it in firefox, or other computer It's everything ok and show me profil page. I use thin server, webrick and apache with passenger and I have same problem.

This is from my log:

```
# I repaired bug
Started GET "/" for 10.10.13.80 at 2012-06-05 09:19:22 +0200
Processing by IndexController#index as HTML
  Rendered index/_top_article.html.erb (4.6ms)
  Rendered index/_side_bar.html.erb (0.0ms)
  Rendered index/index.html.erb within layouts/index (5.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 16ms (Views: 7.6ms | ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)

# I clicked on link /profil/6
Started GET "/error500" for 10.10.13.80 at 2012-06-05 09:19:27 +0200
Processing by ErrorsController#handle500 as HTML
  Rendered errors/handle500.html.erb within layouts/index (0.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 8ms (Views: 6.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.1ms)
```

Comment: Do you use HTTP caching ? Did you clear you browser cache?

Comment: I use ctrl + F5, but I don't clean everything with chrome setings -> clean cache. I don't have this problem with firefox, same problem is on other macbooks with chrome.